# How to optimize the JPA query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a bottleneck in my code, but not able to optimize the query. The part table has a million records and this method is taking more than a minute to execute.
Any suggestion on how to rewrite this query so that the execution happens in seconds?

```
log.info("Starting Part Map...");
            Map<String, List<Part>> exPartsByPartNumber = partRepo.findAll().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Part::getPartNumber));
            log.info("mapped existing parts by pn");
```

---

PartBase.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
//@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@MappedSuperclass
public class PartBase extends AuditEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PART_ID")
    private Integer partId;

    @Column(name = "part_number")
    private String partNumber;

    @Column(name = "part_description")
    private String partDescription;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ESN_ID", nullable = false)
    private Esn esn;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private String quantity;
......}
```

Comment: If you want to return all of that data through HTTP or something, then there is not much you can do. This kind of task will simply be kind of slow. You should rather think if you really need all this data. Maybe you just need to know how many parts have the same part number? Then you could use a query like `select p.partNumber, count(*) from Part p group by p.partNumber`

Comment: tried that approach but this is taking more time in the next phase, where we are matching each partnumber and updating or adding it. when looping to get the parts```for (int i=0; i<inParts.size(); i++) {    
    PartStaging inPart = inParts.get(i);
    Part locatedPart = null;    
    //log.info("before filter query");    
    List<Part> exParts = partRepo.findByPartNumber(exPartsByPartNumber.stream()                   .filter(x ->inPart.getPartNumber().equals(x.getPartNumber()))                  .map(PartsByPartNumber::getPartNumber)                   .findAny() .orElse(null));```

Comment: I'll highlight this again. If you have millions of rows, this will be slow, regardless how you implement it. *Think if you really need all this data*. Maybe ask a new question where you share your actual business requirement, rather than asking why selecting a million rows takes a long time.

Answer (score 0):

One reason your method might be slow is because it's operating on an in-memory copy of every record/instance of the entity. `findAll()` just returns a `List<>`, which means it's basically doing a `SELECT * FROM table` with no `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`. You call `stream()` on that `List` but by that time all the records are pulled over into memory and the in-memory stream is then `collect()`ed with the grouping `Collector`. In other words, using a stream here isn't really helping your performance.

Instead, you could construct things so that the database does the grouping; it might be faster, because that's something DBs are good at. [Here is a tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions) with various techniques for doing aggregation (grouping) in a Spring JPA repository.

Comment: I will use it and let you know

Comment: I have tried to do this via HQL but getting this error "SELECT p.partNumber as partNumber, p as parts"
            + " FROM Part p"
            + " GROUP BY p.partNumber "but getting this error instead - SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - ERROR: column "part0_.part_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 40