# Why this JPA error in running the project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a springboot Hibernate project. The gradle build runs successfully, but when it is trying to run the HQL, it is getting the following error. What am I getting wrong in the HQL

Below is the HQL I am trying to run

```
   @Query("SELECT p.partNumber as partNumber, p as parts"
            + " FROM Part p"
            + " GROUP BY p.partNumber")
    public List<IPartsByPartNumber> findByPartsByPartNumber();
```

Section giving error:

```
log.info("got {} shortage parts loaded", inParts.size());
            log.info("Starting Part Map...");
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<IPartsByPartNumber> exPartsByPartNumber = partRepo.findByPartsByPartNumber();
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            log.info("mapped existing parts by pn and the time is" + time);
            log.info("Actual Model ----->" + Arrays.toString(exPartsByPartNumber.toArray()));
```

Here is the model:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PartsByPartNumber{

    String partNumber;
    
    List<Part> parts;

}
```

Here is the Part class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
//@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@MappedSuperclass
public class PartBase extends AuditEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PART_ID")
    private Integer partId;

    @Column(name = "part_number")
    private String partNumber;

    @Column(name = "part_description")
    private String partDescription;



..........
```

Error:

```
2022-08-14 20:22:12 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.runShortageBulkUpdate - Updating 33392 parts using the local cal celma shortage data
2022-08-14 20:22:12 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.updateCalCelmaParts - updating parts using local cal celma shortage cache data
2022-08-14 20:22:15 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.updateCalCelmaParts - got 11989 shortage parts loaded
2022-08-14 20:22:15 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.updateCalCelmaParts - Starting Part Map...
2022-08-14 20:22:15 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42803
2022-08-14 20:22:15 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - ERROR: column "part0_.part_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 40
2022-08-14 20:22:15 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.updateCalCelmaParts - shortage parts update failed with exception org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2022-08-14 20:22:15 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.updateCalCelmaParts - end
2022-08-14 20:22:15 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.runShortageBulkUpdate - updated -1 parts
2022-08-14 20:22:15 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.saveTask - saving task Cal Celma Shortage Data
2022-08-14 20:22:16 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.runShortageBulkUpdate - Shortage writing to part failed
2022-08-14 20:22:16 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.saveTask - saving task Cal Celma Shortage Data
2022-08-14 20:22:16 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.g.d.o.m.s.CalCelmaShortageDataService.runShortageBulkUpdate - Hana Shortage Transfer Finished
2022-08-14 20:22:16 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.handleError - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: The error is written **"part0_.part_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function** - your sql is wrong.

Comment: I have added the part class..if I want to GroupBy PartNumber what will be my HQL

Comment: The entity that you describe above contains an id, a partnumber, and a description, what exactly can be aggregated?

Comment: Actually I am trying to build a model like 'select p.part_number,count(*) from moa.part as p group by part_number' . Instead of count(*) I want the list of parts

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that **the SQL is wrong**.
What I understood From your comment that, you want to fetch list of parts instead of count result.

As per my understanding, **this can not be done using HQL**.

One solution is popping out in my head right now is, fetch all the data, then iterate through the result set and group them by part_number

This is not the optimum solution though if the table size is very large.

Comment: Can this be done through Native query?

Comment: This user asked a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73323644/how-to-optimize-the-jpa-query) before and it seems that he doesn't want to understand that reading a million of rows is simply going to take a lot of time, regardless how he implements this. I can only write it again, that the user should explain the business requirement, because I doubt that it is "return all the parts from the part table grouped by part number"